# java вызов объекта из класса Controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Вообщем я новичок, сразу начал учиться программировать с java + javafx.
При нажатие кнопки (fxid:prepareRomEvent) , текст в TextField (fxid:nameRomText)  должен записать в переменную. 
Не могу понять, как вызвать объект в другом классе (из класса Controller)
Есть строчка с комментарием  использовать вместо `PrepareRom.prepareRomActivity();`, то все работает нормально (т.к все действия происходят в одном классе).

Собственно код:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("GenUS");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

public class Controller {

    public TextField nameRomText;

    public void prepareRomEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        PrepareRom.prepareRomActivity();
        //System.out.println(getNameRom());
    }

    public void buildRomEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    }

    public String getNameRom() {
        return nameRomText.getText();
    }

}

public class PrepareRom {
    public static void prepareRomActivity(){
        Controller nameRom = new Controller();
        System.out.println(nameRom.getNameRom());
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что следующей строкой `Controller nameRom = new Controller();` Вы просто создадите новый объект типа `Controller`. Поле `nameRomText` не будет указывать на `TextField` в который Вы вводили данные (это `instance поле` значение которому по умолчанию будет присвоено `null`). [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class) показано как получить `Controller`.

Comment: @notaProgrammer привел контроллер к виду как во втором ответе.
Я что-то должен писать в initialize? и как мне теперь вызвать мой объект?

Comment: **1.** `initialize` - это метод жизненного цикла, он вызывается после инициализации контроллера (в Вашем случае `Controller`). В этом методе Вы можете присвоить какие-то начальные значения Вашим компонентам (`TextField`, `TextArea`, `Label`). **2.** Вызывать ничего не нужно, Вы получаете контроллер не так `Controller nameRom = new Controller();`, а так `Controller controller = (Controller) fxmlLoader.getController();` и у него вызываете метод `getNameRom()`. Вот и все.

Comment: @notaProgrammer если программировать gui, а не использовать fxml, смогу ли я не использовать эти костыли?

Comment: Это не костыли. Все работает как нужно, Вы просто еще не понимаете архитектуру JavaFX (со временем поймете). Вы не создаете вручную экземпляр контроллера, не создаете слушатели всевозможных событий, не присваиваете вручную данные, которые Вы ввели в `TextField`, допустим. Все это "делается за Вас". Вам лишь нужно связать JavaFX компонент с помощью fx:id и в поле соответствующего события ввести название метода, который будет вызван. Поэтому, если уже все сделано за Вас, то логично, что нужно получить контроллер, а не создавать новый. Если не использовать fxml все это нужно будет делать вручную.

Comment: @notaProgrammer можете сделать пример. у меня не выходит

Comment: @notaProgrammer написал простенькую программу, пожалуйста исправьте ошибку. [проект для idea и eclipse](https://yadi.sk/d/Qi1FkkAz3TjRdi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При разборе fxml-файла в методе `FXMLLoader.load()` создается объект класса, указанного в атрибуте `fx:controller`.
При нажатии на кнопку вызывается метод `prepareRomEvent()` именно для этого объекта контроллера.
И этот же объект контроллера нужно использовать в статической функции, а не создавать новый оператором `new`.

Передать этот объект в функцию можно, например, через параметр функции:

```
public class PrepareRom {
    public static void prepareRomActivity(Controller nameRom) {
        System.out.println(nameRom.getNameRom());
    }
}
```

И при вызове этой функции передать ссылку на текущий объект контроллера (`this`):

```
public class Controller {

    public TextField nameRomText;

    public void prepareRomEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        PrepareRom.prepareRomActivity(this);
    }

    public String getNameRom() {
        return nameRomText.getText();
    }
}
```

**Дополнение:**

> а как сделать для других методов в классе?(это будет работать только
>   для prepareRomActivity, хотел бы для всего класса,ну или чтобы
>   вызываемому объекту из этого тоже была возможность управлять
>   контролером)  – vngreez

Можно методы класса `PrepareRom` сделать нестатическими и работать с объектом этого класса.
При создании этого объекта передавать ему контроллер в параметре конструктора. Создание этого объекта сделать, например, в конструкторе контроллера:

```
public class Controller {

    private PrepareRom prepareRom;

    public TextField nameRomText;

    public Controller() {
        prepareRom = new PrepareRom(this);
    }

    public void prepareRomEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        prepareRom.prepareRomActivity();
    }

    public String getNameRom() {
        return nameRomText.getText();
    }

}

public class PrepareRom {
    Controller nameRom;

    public PrepareRom(Controller controller) {
        nameRom = controller;
    }

    public void prepareRomActivity() {
        System.out.println(nameRom.getNameRom());
    }
}
```

Создать объект класса `PrepareRom` в контроллере можно и по-другому: прямо перед вызовом нужного метода в проверке на `null`, в методе `initialize()`, или воспользоваться внедрением зависимости.

Comment: а как сделать для других методов в классе?(это будет работать только для prepareRomActivity, хотел бы для всего класса,ну или чтобы вызываемому объекту из этого тоже была возможность управлять контролером)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: а можно поподробнее о initialize() , это будет не единственный класс, хотелось бы универсальное решение.

Comment: После того, как `FXMLLoader` создаст все объекты .fxml-файла, он вызывает метод `initialize()`
контроллера. Это может быть либо реализация интерфейса `Initializable`, либо просто `(@FXML | public) void initialize() {...}`.
Как именно это происходит, можно посмотреть в исходном файле `FXMLLoader.java`.
Возможно, в качестве универсального решения, в вашем случае больше подойдет какой-либо инструмент внедрения зависимости (dependency injection).