# javafx ошибка в проекте

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, fxml

написал простенькую программу для самообучения, на javafx. Возникает ошибка, прошу объяснить, что делаю не так и показать как исправить.

[*Cсылка*](https://yadi.sk/d/Qi1FkkAz3TjRdi)

программирую на idea, но экспортировал также для eclipse

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity {
  static FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

{
    try {
        Pane p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml").openStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static Controller controller = (Controller) fxmlLoader.getController();
public static void mainActivity() {
   controller.setTextLabel(controller.getTexField()); //Вот тут ошибка (строка 21)
}
}
```

===

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Controller implements Initializable {
public TextField textField;
public Label textLabel;

public void okAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    MainActivity.mainActivity(); // тут ошибка (строка 17)
}
public void setTextLabel(String str) {
    textLabel.setText(str);
}

public String getTexField() {
    return textLabel.getText();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

}
}
```

====

Ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.MainActivity.mainActivity(MainActivity.java:21)
    at sample.Controller.okAction(Controller.java:17)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Опубликуйте текст ошибки и кусок кода, где она возникает

Comment: @AntonShchyrov код добавил

Comment: Можно было не вызывать fxml, а сделать иначе:
[Решение тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/802773/java-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-controller/805704#805704)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResourse(/sample/sample.fxml)); 
Если ошибка в строке с fxmlloader. У меня та же ошибка была

Comment: не помогает этот способ